# How to refresh window but still retain previous drawn objects

Tags: processing

I would like to refresh the background of the window as the goal of my program is to connect points together. However, every time a new last point is made, the original (first) point will connect to the new last point while removing the previous connection.

I am able to connect the original point to the last point. However, the previous line is still shown on the window.

I have tried refreshing the background by inserting 'background(255)' into the 'void draw()' section so that it will constantly refresh after 'if (mousePressed == true)'

However, it will completely wipe the previously drawn objects.

```
//set global variables
final int N_PARTITIONS = 10;
        int PrevX = -1;
            int PrevY = -1;
        int count = 0;
     int gridx = 0;
  int gridy = 0;
int OriginalX;
int OriginalY;
PVector[] Vector = new PVector[1]; {
Vector[0] = new PVector();

}
//CREATING WINDOW SIZE
void setup() {
  size(600, 360);
    surface.setResizable(true); 
    background(255);
}



void mouseClicked() {

   if(count == 0) {
        Vector[0].x = mouseX;
        Vector[0].y = mouseY;
     }
      count++;

              CallEllipse();
             if (PrevX != -1) {
                 line(PrevX, PrevY, mouseX, mouseY);
             }
             if (count >= 3) {
               DrawLine();
             }



      PrevX = mouseX;
      PrevY = mouseY;

    PVector[] PrevLine = new PVector[1];
   PrevLine[0] = new PVector();
     PrevLine[0].x = PrevX;
     PrevLine[0].y = PrevY;


}


void CallEllipse() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, N_PARTITIONS, N_PARTITIONS);
}

void DrawLine() {
  line(Vector[0].x, Vector[0].y, mouseX, mouseY);
}

void grid() {
while(gridx >= 0 & gridy >= 0) {
   stroke(195);
    line(gridx, 0, gridx, height);
      line(0, gridy, width, gridy);
gridx += width/N_PARTITIONS;
gridy += height/N_PARTITIONS;
    }
}

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed == true) {
    mouseClicked();
    background(255);
}
}
```

I want the previous last line to be removed and a new line to connect the original point and the new last point.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general approaches:

**Option 1:** Store all of your points in a data structure, like an array or `ArrayList`. Each frame, draw the background, and then redraw all of your points. This option is a few more lines of code, but it allows you to make more complex animations.

**Option 2:** Draw all of your points to a `PGraphics` instance, and then draw that instance to the frame. This would allow you to separate the background from the foreground. This option is less code, but you can't dynamically update the points after they're drawn to the `PGraphics`.

Which option you choose is up to you and what makes the most sense for your goals. You can find more info about both approaches in the [reference](https://processing.org/reference/). You might also try googling something like "Processing PGraphics" for a ton of results. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I will try option 1 as i am mainly focusing on using arrays :D